# uploadify inside fancybox - not working

Tags: javascript, fancybox, uploadify

Has anyone succesfully used uploadify inside fancybox? If I create a form setup on a normal page uploadify works perfectly, but if I take the exact same code and puts inside a fancybox it does not. The uploadfield is changed to uploadify, but when calling uploadifyUpload on my button the js of uploadify gives an error. Any experience or ideas on this?

Comment: Is the code for uploadify (initialisation and options) on the parent page (where the link is) or on the HTML page loaded through fancybox?

Comment: there is only one page and the uploadfield is inside the div which is converted to fancybox - init for uploadify and fancybox looks in short like this; `$(document).ready(function () { $('#file_upload').uploadify(); $('#mydiv').fancybox(); });`. The code gives and error when trying to execute an uploadify function, e.g. `$('#file_upload').uploadifySettings();` or `$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();`

Comment: Can you post some code?  I'am able to get uploadify work inside fancybox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late response, wasnt notifed about your comment - the code is now changed to use another jQuery upload script, one from lagoscript.org, which I also modified a bit to better fit my needs. This way I also avoid the use of Flash which could become an issue in the project I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but there doesn't seem to be a good answer anywhere after I did a search, so I wanted to add one here:

The solution is initialize uploadify each time the fancybox window is opened, by doing it in the onStart() handler.

You'll have to add code to reset uploadify if it had already been initialized (e.g. fancybox has already been opened before). You can do this by adding code within the onStart() handler and before initializing uploadify, similar to this:

```
$('#ID_FOR_FANCYBOX').fancybox({
  // other fancybox settings...
  'onStart': function() {

    // check if it has already been initialized
    if ($('#file_queue').hasClass("uploadifyQueue"))
    {
      // remove uploadify 
      $('#file_queue').removeClass('uploadifyQueue');
      $("#file_upload").unbind("uploadifySelect");
      swfobject.removeSWF('file_uploadUploader');

      // reset the html so we can initialize uploadify again
      $('#modal_upload .footer').html('<p><input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" /> or <a href="#" onclick="$.fancybox.close();return false;">cancel</a></p>');
    }

    // init uploadify here...

});
```

Comment: great - thanks, I will experiment with this next time I need something similar. I ended up using a upload-solution which uploads using an iframe.